# List of User fields not available in Apex

Tags: standard-objects, user, user-record, user-admin

I am looking to write some custom functionality for creating a [`User`](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm).

The problem I am facing is that some of the standard User fields don't appear to be available through the API. I found this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kkz9AAA) about the `Accessibility Mode` field that appears on the standard UI. According to that idea, Salesforce Support discovered that it's not actually a field at all but a, "User Interface feature that is not stored on the User object, but is merely referenced."

My question is, does anyone know of a list of User fields that are in this same state? I can't seem to find access to a few of the fields available during standard User creation:

- `Force.com Quick Access Menu`
- `Color-Blind Palette on Charts`
- `Allow Forecasting`
- etc...

Comment: Reminds me of the [OrderProduct's TotalPrice field](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/32893/154) that is a "ui calculated field" not available in Apex.

Comment: It does seem eerily similar @PeterKnolle. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: So, you just need a list of such field?

Comment: Yes, basically @AtulRajguru9. It would be fantastic to include some explanation of why those fields are unavailable as well, but a list would be great as well. I want to make sure I am not missing fields that are available through some obscure method.

Comment: Are you certain you're not looking for `ForecastEnabled`? I show that as queryable under `User` and was just able to confirm that. As an FYI, my Dev Org shows there's also a parent of `User` in `UserRole` called `Forecast User` that includes that permission. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_role.htm.

Comment: I believe the `Force.com Quick Access Menu` is called `UserPermissionsWorkDotComUserFeature`. See  `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm for more.

Comment: Nice finds @crmprogdev - I will have to check those out. This is the main reason I asked this question, to see if I could find someone who had compiled a list and check off fields I could not find.

Comment: @JesseAltman, Nice to be able to assist someone who's helped me a lot in the past for a change. The Object Reference comes in pretty handy, but the descriptions can still be obscure. Forecasting has changed significantly since `ForecastEnabled` was originally enabled. `Quick Access Menu` required a bit of comparison with the actual menu to confirm. I also used Ajax Tools to poke around a bit which I still prefer it over some of the other tools for it's thoroughness. This reminds me of hacking the Windows Registry; something I was always good at. :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried to relate API Name with UI label and here is what I found.

Missing field in API but Available on UI

```
Accessibility Mode  
NewsAllow Forecasting  
Color-Blind Palette on Charts  
End of day  
Force.com Flow User  
Force.com Quick Access Menu =  
Make Setup My Default Landing Page  
Mobile Configuration  
Mobile Push Registrations   
Receive Approval Request Emails  
Receive Salesforce CRM Content Alerts as Daily Digest  
Receive Salesforce CRM Content Email Alerts  
Salesforce Classic User  
Salesforce1 User  
Send Apex Warning Emails  
Service Cloud User  
Show View State in Development Mode  
Start of day  
Time-Based Token  
Used Data Space  
Used File Space  
User License
```

Here are field already mapped.

```
UI Column   =   API Name  
Alias   =   Alias  
Call Center =   CallCenterId  
Address =   City , Street, State, Country,PostalCode   
Nickname    =   CommunityNickname  
Company =   CompanyName  
Created By  =   CreatedById  
Delegated Approver  =   DelegatedApproverId  
Department  =   Department  
Division    =   Division  
Email   =   Email  
Email Encoding  =   EmailEncodingKey  
Employee Number =   EmployeeNumber  
Extension   =   Extension  
Fax =   Fax  
Federation ID   =   FederationIdentifier  
Active  =   IsActive  
Language    =   LanguageLocaleKey  
Last Login  =   LastLoginDate  
Last Password Change or Reset   =   LastPasswordChangeDate  
Locale  =   LocaleSidKey  
Manager =   ManagerId  
Mobile  =   MobilePhone  
Name    =   Name  
Phone   =   Phone  
Profile =   ProfileId  
Admin Newsletter    =   ReceivesAdminInfoEmails  
Time Zone   =   TimeZoneSidKey  
Title   =   Title   
Username    =   Username   
Knowledge User  =   UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser  
Marketing User  =   UserPermissionsMarketingUser  
Offline User    =   UserPermissionsOfflineUser   
Salesforce CRM Content User =   UserPermissionsSFContentUser   
Site.com Contributor User   =   UserPermissionsSiteforceContributorUser   
Site.com Publisher User =   UserPermissionsSiteforcePublisherUser   
Work.com User   =   UserPermissionsWorkDotComUserFeature   
Development Mode    =   UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode  
Role    =   UserRoleId
Allow Forecasting  =  ForecastEnabled **  
Newsletter  =  ReceivesInfoEmails **
```

PS: This fields are mapped as per my understanding. Please feel free to correct me.

** Revised by @crmprogdev on 03/19/15

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! If anyone notices something wrong, feel free to update the answer but this was perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Have edited and revised the last two entries. Verified in my DevOrg.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 I am not able to get the User details fields also.. i am getting only one field. Cna u please give me some link to get fields of User object.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "not able to get the User details fields also" how are you fetching User details ?

Answer (score 0):

there are other mapped fields like:

```
Saleforce1 user=UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some additional field mappings:

```
Salesforce Classic User - UserPermissionsMobileUser
Service Cloud User - UserPermissionsSupportUser
live agent user - UserPermissionsLiveAgentUser
```