# Anybody knows where we can enable/disable "Make Setup My Default Landing Page" of user record programatically?

Tags: apex, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org, user-management

I've been trying to understand where we can toggle "Make Setup My Default Landing Page" field of user?

My intention is to build a scratch org and at the same time I want to disable this after scratch org is created. So I'm looking for any field update but I am unable to pin-point a dedicated field for this in User record.

Can anybody help or have any idea where this value is stored?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you can't. There's a [number of fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/69438/2984) you can't access via any API, and are only available in Setup. It's theoretically possible to use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) to make the check for you, but that's going to require some additional steps, and probably outside the scope of this site.