# Not able to access TotalPrice in OrderItem

Tags: trigger, soql, community, order, orderitem

Trying to write trigger on Order item .I have created new field called discount.I have to perform formula using trigger on TotalPrice(TotalPrice=Discount*TotalPrice).I am not able to access TotalPrice hence getting this error "Innvalid field TotalPrice for SObject OrderItem
"
Not understanding how to access TotalPrice fields .

```
 trigger Totalprice on OrderItem (after insert,after update)  {
      if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate){
           for(OrderItem oi : trigger.new) {
               Oi.TotalPrice=  Oi.Discount__c*Oi.TotalPrice;
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Please check fields api name for OrderItem here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_orderitem.htm

Comment: I have done that .I cannot find TotalPrice.I have to access TotalPrice

Comment: Here is a Discussions related to your requirement please refer it.. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32893/why-isnt-orderproduct-totalprice-standard-field-available-in-formula-merge-fiel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TotalPrice field is not available in OrderItem object it is being calculated

`OrderItem.TotalPrice = OrderItem.UnitPrice * OrderItem.Quantity`

so query for the quantity and unitprice and use above formula.

Hope this helps you.