# Standard Field not available for Roll-up Summary

Tags: roll-up-summary, field-service-lightning

I am creating a series of Roll-up Summaries on the standard WorkOrder Object, summarizing the standard TotalPrice field on the WorkOrderLineItem Object.  However, this field does not appear on the list of available fields to aggregate.

Some notes:

- TotalPrice is not a Formula field, but a Currency field.
- There is a standard Roll-up Summary field on WorkOrder that summarizes the TotalPrice field
- To answer questions about why I don't use the above-mentioned field, we are looking to aggregate specific subsets of WorkOrderLineItems in separate fields
- We are not at our Limit of total number of Roll-up Summary fields on Work Order

I cannot find any reason why this field would not be available.  It is the same concept and data model as Opportunities vs Opportunity Products and the TotalPrice field is available to aggregate there. I cannot find documentation regarding any limits on Rull-up Summaries looking at a specific field, however, there is currently just the 1 Standard field aggregating it today and I know you can have more than that.

Comment: Maybe something to do with permissions? I just checked in my org and I can create a Roll-up summary field on the (Standard) Work Order on a custom currency field on the work order line item without any issues

Comment: @utm No, I have full system admin permissions and read/write to all fields in question here.

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32893/why-isnt-orderproduct-totalprice-standard-field-available-in-formula-merge-fiel; Use DLRS as a workaround

Comment: @DC-Fencer does it work on other objects for you or do you have the same issues?

Comment: @utm It works fine with other Objects. The Opportunity-> Opportunity Product is the same Data Model with the same fields (Unit Price, Quantity, Subtotal and Total Price) and Roll-up fields work just fine in that context.

Comment: In addition to this, TotalPrice is not even available to make a Formula field around.  My workaround for this was to create a new Formula field that just mimiced the value of Total Price but I could not add TotalPrice into the formula.  I instead just did Unit Price * Quantity which gets me the value I want and was able to create the rollup field around that.